# ArcGIS Online - Linking Symbology between layers

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I have two sets of data presented on a web map using ArcGIS Online (Classic). These data are points and lines. The points represent a building, and the lines feed out from the points representing a linear flow of data. Each line is associated with a single point, I have over 700 000 points and the same number of lines.

I would like to copy the colour of the point, to the associated line. It does not matter if the colours repeat (they will considering the number of points). It is more to allow a user an easy way to understand which line is associated with its source point. I have written some Arcade in the pop-up that links the two, I am looking for a way to visually link the two datasets.

The attribute tables for the points and lines are identical. There is a name field in both layers.

Is there a way to ensure that the lines and their associated source points are coloured the same?

Comment: Are you saying you have 700,000 unique colours in the point layer? I'm surprised anything works? That would be an insane number of symbols that would be loaded up in the Table of contents?

Comment: While there are 700 000 unique features per feature layer - 2 in total -, they are not displayed on the web map at the same time and there is a duplication of colours in the ToC. The map performance is adequate. The main issue is finding a way to visually link the line to the source point by way colours.